# Can't input new line in multiline edittext box(enter button will change focus to next input field)

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiline, enter

I have an `EditText` field with following java code:

```
EditText edittxt=new EditText(cntxt);
edittxt.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
edittxt.setMinLines(minLines);
edittxt.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
edittxt.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

But it will change focus to next `EditText` field when I type "enter" button on soft keyboard. So the problem is user can't input new lines in this multiline text box.

Anyone know this issue?  I've searched on google. Most of those solutions are how to disable "enter" button.

Comment: see that u have added this code android:singleLine="false"

Comment: Thanks Adil. Is there a java code to diable singleline? I need to add edittext by programing.

Comment: you have a function `etNote2.setSingleLine(false);`

Comment: Try putting the TYPE_CLASS_TEXT for inputType `edittxt.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);` . Have noticed many a times that Flags like `MULTI_LINE` do not work until you specify the type of input edittext should have.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the IME option [setImeOptions(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setImeOptions%28int%29) and set it [IME_NULL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html)